# How to run script as restricted user?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sudo, account-restrictions

I need to create a very restricted user on Linux that will have restrictive list of commands to run, be able to see some log files and and to run the script from /opt/bin folder.
I cannot use Jailkit tools (already implemented for another type of users, and as I could see, the jailkit conf file can serve one type of user). What is the possible solution? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you might have accidentally created two accounts.  If so, you should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/224384/ganna and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/224385/ganna07.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try using `facl` to have read, write and execute permission for required users. And for others nil permission